# Node - Electron - FS (save/read) Crashes electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to build an electron app and i can't seem to get FS (file-system) to work without crashing Electron.

I'm not getting any informative error messages, and I could not find anything online about this.

The code is super-simple, Electron is set up and executed properly, and loads the following script file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
require('jsdom-global')();
var $ = require('jquery');

console.log( path.resolve(__dirname, 'starter.json') );

// load starter data:
fs.readFile( path.resolve(__dirname, 'starter.json') , 'utf8', function( err, data ){
    console.log( err, data );
});
```

DevTools disconnects instantly, which apparently means an operation was so expensive that it crashed electron.

The path to the .json file is correct, none of the packages are modified, and Electron's main.js uses the standard set up.

Answer (score 1):

Nm, turns out it was the jsdom-global package, removed it, works fine now.